# Failed an audit which I think is link only

Tags: discussion, first-post-review, specific-audit

Today I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/29200710) in the "First posts" queue. I'm aware that the system chose this post as an audit since it's an accepted answer with 13 upvotes and awarded with a bounty. Nevertheless I think that it is just a link only answer.

I'm not an SME so my judgement might also be wrong. If I'm correct, I'd like to ask a mod to remove that post from the audits.

Comment: _"coverage.py can do this, with dynamic contexts"_ **is** an answer. Not a great answer, but an answer nonetheless.

Comment: I added a comment indicating what would make it better. You could have done the same thing...

Comment: Link only is something like "Have a look at this article [...](...)"

Comment: @JeanneDark _Does this answer your question?_ I already know that post. I don't think that it is a dupe since I asked about a specific answer.

Comment: Don't worry about it too much - the distinction between "link-only" answers and "links to an answer" is a fine one and confuses many. NAA the latter, downvote the former (and/or ask the author to expand).

Comment: "The answer can be found over here: <link>. Notice that this is not necessarily the same thing as a "link-only answer" (although there is much overlap). In particular, answers where the link itself is the answer to the question are excluded and should not be flagged. For example, where the link text is a function/API and the link target is the associated documentation. Another example can be found here."

Comment: @yivi as I wrote, I'm not an SME. Is _dynamic contexts_ enough information for someone knowing coverage.py to know what one could do?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Isn't just linking to a library without an usage example by definition "link only"?

Comment: I don't need to be an SME to know that _"coverage.py can do this, with dynamic contexts"_ is an attempt to answer. By stripping the link the post reads like an answer, even if as I said earlier, it's not a particularly great answer.

Comment: A good way to judge if an answer is link only, is to strip the answer of the link mentally, and then think if it would be helpful in any way. If you strip the link, you are left with: _"coverage.py can do this, with dynamic contexts."_, which is arguably an answer. But it's not a good answer, and it's sad that it has 13 upvotes.

Comment: @10Rep that's what I'm usually doing. I didn't count _coverage.py_ as helpful information since the question is tagged with it and thought that _dynamic contexts_ was to less of an information to be helpful. Looks like I was wrong with the latter.

Comment: @BillTür - yeah it's borderline. It gets away on a technicality (plus 13 upvotes and a bounty). I wouldn't call it a good answer too. Don't sweat it, I guess, these things happen.

Comment: @OlegValter No worries, I'm totally relaxed ;-). You're right, these things happen.

Comment: @10Rep if one does not have experience with a particular topic it is very hard to judge what is/isn't useful. It very well could be that every single user of the library found "dynamic context" is *the answer* they were looking for and see no need for any other details...

Comment: python is a bad tag 13 upvotes for a link only answer

Comment: In no way is that "link-only". This is a great audit; I hope you and many others can use it to improve your reviewing process.

Comment: @nbk there's even worse... but regex is also pretty bad, right?

Comment: @CodyGray you make in the last time irrational decisions and display a bad judgement, that is so clearly a link only answer that it hurts

Comment: If it were link only, then it would consist of *only a link*. It doesn't. This couldn't possibly be more clear. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer (where a very similar answer is given as an example)